# Unity freeze after random amount of time in debug mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, freeze, rider

I have some problems with the Unity debugger.
Sometimes, after inspecting the execution step by step without any problems, if I try to resume the program or just go to the next step, Unity freezes as if the debugger is still blocking the execution.
In the editor, the debugger clearly shows that we have resumed execution but I can't get back to the Unity window. The only thing I can do is go to the task manager and force Unity to stop. Some additional information:

- This can happen in any project
- It is not related to a specific instruction, it can happen anywhere, randomly.
- I tried waiting a long time to see if it was just a running instruction.
- I tried to stop/restart the debugger.
- I tried to close/open my editor (JetBrains Rider)
- I'm using Unity 2019 on Windows 11
- Other employees do not have this bug

Nothing works. I don't know why this is happening, it's really annoying that I can't figure out what's going on... I didn't find anything about this specific bug on google

Comment: Use debug break all so you can see where the code is executing and see why code is being blocked.

Comment: Is your computer able to handle your project and Unity in debug mode?

Comment: @jdweng Debug break all is a setting in unity? I don't find it.

Comment: @MaximilianFischer Are you talking about performance? If so, yes, it can easily run Unity in debug mode and much more.

Comment: You can try getting help from the official support on the Unity forum. They might be able to help you more.

Comment: Break All only appears when code is running in the debug menu.

Comment: @jdweng ok I think I understood. But it is precisely when I am in break all mode that this bug appears. When I try to reach the next instruction or when I try to resume execution. So I can't do much more to see why the code is blocked. Example : the program is paused on the instruction "i = 2;" I press F10 to go to the next one, there the debugger seems not to work anymore (the buttons "next step" or "resume" are grayed, but the program is not resumed)

Comment: Did you look at the call stack?  menu Debug: Window : Call Stack

Comment: Sure you're not running into an infinite loop? e.g. a variable passed to a coroutine to control it's while loop is incorrect. Usually things like this are logical errors rather than problems with the environment. That said, you could always try and reinstall Unity + VS.

Comment: @jdweng I'm using Rider not VS (this is a requirement of my company), I don't have the menus Debug: etc... But in the call stack there is nothing specific when this happens.

Comment: If it its happening randomly it sound like an event stops occurring.  It could be something like a TCP connection closed so no more data is being received (or similar).

Comment: @jdweng The other employees of my company don't have this bug on their computers (I should have mentioned it at the beginning). I think it's a bug in my installation, but where? I don't know.

Comment: @Absinthe I will try to reinstall Unity, but I already tried it a long time ago... (We use a specific stable version for the project). Maybe it's because of Windows 11? I'm the only one using it...

Comment: Is your PC same brand as others (maybe Dell)?  Try getting motherboard drivers updated.